# EC2 after restart can not access via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I was connecting my ec2 instance via ssh well,after adding new EBS volume restarted the machine by 'sudo shutdown -r now'
And after that I tried to access by using follwing command:

```
ssh -v  -i primary_key.pem ubuntu@ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

which is retuning like below:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/caveman/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com [23.22.245.160] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file primary_key.pem type -1
debug1: identity file primary_key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'ec2-23-22-245-160.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/caveman/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: primary_key.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

What is wrong?Any point that I am missing?

Comment: When you say `after adding new EBS volume`, what do you mean exactly ? Did you replace the root EBS volume or did you add an additional EBS volume ?

Comment: I have added an additional EBS.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

Indicates that you disabled password authentication. You can only authenticate using a public key (while having the corresponding private key).

The two consecutive lines

```
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
```

indicates that you are using an RSA private key that could be read fine, but that its public counterpart could not be authenticated by the server.

Some options to try:

- Double check that you are using the correct key.
- Double check the username. Maybe you made a typo when creating the account or did you connect using your own username earlier when copying over the key (`ssh-copy-id`).
- In case you have access to the server in another way, check the permissions (and ownership!) on the complete `~ubuntu/.ssh` directory recursively to be strict enough (OpenSSH will refuse access if too permissive).

  - `~ubuntu/.ssh/` directory should be owned by the user and have mode 0700 (`drwx------`)
  - `~ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys` file should be owned by the user and have mode 0600 (`-rw-------`)
- If you did not disable `PasswordAuthentication` in your SSH daemon, this may indicate that the password has been reset to be empty or that the user account is disabled (`usermod -L`) for login or expired. Try logging in with a different user (maybe `root` a regular user account).
- If you did disable `PasswordAuthentication` in the configuration file of your SSH daemon but didn't restart it right after that, then the change may only become active after a reboot. See the option below for how to fix this.
- Do you have direct access to the text console using a control panel in EC2? I'm not familiar with Amazon AWS, but I think you should have this option. Then you should be able to login using the console to reset your password and gain access via SSH.
- Try to shut down your EC2 instance and attach the storage device to another instance. Mount it and do a manual password recovery. Re-attach it back to the original instance and it should be fixed.
- After you gain access again, check that your server hasn't compromised. Changes in configuration triggered only after a reboot may indicate that it has. I have seen this happening on several servers.

Comment: Thanks. my case was the ownership of the directory ~ubuntu/.ssh.