# Amazonubuntu ec2 is not responding via ssh

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

It used to work but now it won't respond.

`ssh -i aws-niklas140428.pem ubuntu@54.72.xxx.x`

It does respond via HTTP though and I can restart it in the webGUI at aws.amazon.com

How can I find the cause for the inconvenience? It does not answer via ping either. What is wrong?

Comment: See also [EC2 after restart can not access via ssh](http://serverfault.com/q/429190/168875)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl It was just a DNS / routing problem. I changed to another provider (Swedish Telia) and then it's all good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possibly an IP address of your EC2 instance has changed, since you have restarted it.

Check in Amazon EC2 console for new IP address.

Comment: That, or his local IP changed and is no longer allowed to SSH per the security groups.

Comment: The server ip is 54.72.176.8 that responds via HTTP but I can't ping it. I can open a browser and browse my http server. I can neither ping nor ssh to the server. I never saw anything like this before.

Comment: Can you SSH using Java client from EC2 console?

Comment: @NiklasRosencrantz EC2's security groups block ping traffic by default.

Comment: Thanks, it was just a DNS/routing issue and when I now changed ISP then it's all good and connects.